# Overlaping rectangels and clipping at the bottom in opengl

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I have to make some 3D figures using opengl (the older versions). I created 3 `GL_POLYGON` rectangles that are connected to one another and which have different colors.

My problem is that when the figure rotates the last color added (last added rectangle) is always above the other ones. For example the cyan one is above the pink and the yellow one, and the pink one is above the yellow one. I also noted some clipping at the bottom of the figure, which I think is caused by `gluPerspective()`. What I'm trying to achieve is having the eye look from z+ to the center and the figure rotating around the y+ axis ( which I think I managed to  do) and also to have the overlapping and clipping removed.

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

The code is bellow:

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main()
{
int     width, height;
int     frame = 0;
bool    running = true;

glfwInit();

if( !glfwOpenWindow( 700, 800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

glfwSetWindowTitle("GLFW Application");

while(running)
{
    frame++;

    glfwGetWindowSize( &width, &height );
    height = height > 0 ? height : 1;

    glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 65.0f, (GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height, 1.0f, 100.0f );


    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );


    glRotatef(frame, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


    glColor3ub(255,255,0);
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
      glVertex3f(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(5.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
     glColor3ub(255,0,255);
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
      glVertex3f(5.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
      glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
      glVertex3f(0.0f, 10.0f, -2.0f);
      glVertex3f(5.0f, 10.0f, -2.0f);
    glEnd();
    glColor3ub(0,255,255);
    glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
      glVertex3f(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
      glVertex3f(5.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
      glVertex3f(5.0f, 10.0f, -2.0f);
      glVertex3f(5.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glfwSwapBuffers();

    running = !glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED);}

glfwTerminate();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: 0/10 and dive a bit into documentations...

Comment: @j-p I tried the documentation and I just couldn't wrap my head around all the stuff. I wouldn't be asking for help without first looking the stuff up.

Comment: I don't see depth feature in your code, try looking for `depth buffer` and `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, if not implemented, drawing order rules...

Comment: @j-p Thank you my friend I added `glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );` and `glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT+GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );` and it worked. You can post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see depth feature in your code, try looking for `depth buffer` and `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, if not implemented, drawing order rules..